# How to profile the size of a library

Tags: python, python-3.x, memory-leaks, profiling, memory-profiling

So, I'm stuck in quite a pickle. I have a library that, when imported, occupies roughly 2.6GB.

I assumed this was from it's rather large dependencies, but when adding them all up I came at around 0.8GB of memory, no anywhere near enough to explain the size.

I tried 3x profilers:

1. `memory-profiler` -- doesn't work, just shows the size of the import as a whole
2. `guppy` (specifically the `.heap()` functionality from it -- gave up after not being able to get anything meaningful from it's output
3. `pympler` -- doesn't seem to count import (I think?)... basically after I import the 2.6GB library it counts a total of 0.09GB used, which is odd.

What I really want is a profiler that would lead me in the right direction, e.g. tell me how much memory each file consumes after being imported. I'm considering doing this manually (breakpoints that will trigger on import + analyzing memory usage). But I'm curios if there's any other way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I develop guppy3 so I will give an answer for guppy. I am much less familiar with other profilers. Here's some of the methods I would utilize (you can combine them too; say, "dominated set of producer profile" is also valid):

### reference point

If you can measure the heap a point in time before everything was imported, you can set a reference point and measure a relative heap at a later point in time:

```
>>> import guppy
>>> hp = guppy.hpy()
>>> hp.setref()
>>> import wave
>>> hp.heap()
Partition of a set of 777 objects. Total size = 86,330 bytes.
 Index   Count   %       Size   %   Cumulative  % Kind (class / dict of class)
     0     213  27     22,258  26      22,258  26 str
     1     209  27     16,736  19      38,994  45 tuple
     2      67   9      9,648  11      48,642  56 function
     3      62   8      8,928  10      57,570  67 types.CodeType
     4     130  17      8,172   9      65,742  76 bytes
     5       6   1      6,216   7      71,958  83 type
     6       6   1      4,192   5      76,150  88 dict of type
     7       3   0      2,760   3      78,910  91 dict of module
     8      26   3      2,080   2      80,990  94 types.BuiltinMethodType
     9       2   0        832   1      81,822  95 types.FrameType
<16 more rows. Type e.g. '_.more' to view.>
```

### producer profile

If you have Python 3.8+, you can use guppy's producer profile to find the set of objects whose innermost frame of allocation resides in the file:

```
>>> import tracemalloc
>>> tracemalloc.start()
>>> import wave
>>> import guppy
>>> hp = guppy.hpy()
>>> hp.heap() & hp.Prod(wave.__file__)
Partition of a set of 82 objects. Total size = 13,896 bytes.
 Index   Count   %       Size   %   Cumulative  % Kind (class / dict of class)
     0      50  61      6,800  49       6,800  49 function
     1       3   4      3,192  23       9,992  72 type
     2       3   4      2,584  19      12,576  91 dict of type
     3       9  11        360   3      12,936  93 types.CellType
     4       6   7        328   2      13,264  95 tuple
     5       5   6        320   2      13,584  98 types.GetSetDescriptorType
     6       3   4        216   2      13,800  99 builtins.weakref
     7       3   4         96   1      13,896 100 int
```

This will not include anything that is indirectly allocated:

```
>>> import tracemalloc
>>> tracemalloc.start()
>>> import guppy
>>> hp = guppy.hpy()
>>> hp.setref()
>>> import wave
>>> heap = hp.heap()
>>> heap.byprod
/home/zhuyifei1999/guppy3/guppy/heapy/Classifiers.py:1198: UserWarning: Unable to determine sizeof(PyGC_Head) from _testcapi.SIZEOF_PYGC_HEAD, assuming 16
  return self.mod.hv.cli_prod(memo)
Partition of a set of 688 objects. Total size = 77,934 bytes.
 Index   Count   %       Size   %   Cumulative  % Producer (line of allocation)
     0     471  68     45,835  59      45,835  59 <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>:647
     1      36   5      4,760   6      50,595  65 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:228
     2       8   1      2,576   3      53,171  68 /usr/lib/python3.9/wave.py:275
     3       8   1      2,576   3      55,747  72 /usr/lib/python3.9/wave.py:94
     4       8   1      2,040   3      57,787  74 /usr/lib/python3.9/chunk.py:51
     5       7   1      1,800   2      59,587  76 /usr/lib/python3.9/collections/__init__.py:497
     6       4   1      1,680   2      61,267  79 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:36
     7       7   1      1,584   2      62,851  81 /usr/lib/python3.9/wave.py:84
     8       6   1        770   1      63,621  82 <unknown>:0
     9       5   1        468   1      64,089  82 <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>:123
<89 more rows. Type e.g. '_.more' to view.>
>>> heap - hp.Prod(wave.__file__)
Partition of a set of 605 objects. Total size = 63,918 bytes.
 Index   Count   %       Size   %   Cumulative  % Kind (class / dict of class)
     0     196  32     20,946  33      20,946  33 str
     1      61  10     10,736  17      31,682  50 types.CodeType
     2     134  22      9,584  15      41,266  65 tuple
     3     124  20      7,960  12      49,226  77 bytes
     4       3   0      3,024   5      52,250  82 type
     5       3   0      2,712   4      54,962  86 dict of module
     6      16   3      2,176   3      57,138  89 function
     7      26   4      1,872   3      59,010  92 types.BuiltinMethodType
     8       3   0      1,512   2      60,522  95 dict of type
     9       2   0        800   1      61,322  96 types.FrameType
<14 more rows. Type e.g. '_.more' to view.>
>>> _.byprod
Partition of a set of 605 objects. Total size = 63,918 bytes.
 Index   Count   %       Size   %   Cumulative  % Producer (line of allocation)
     0     471  78     45,835  72      45,835  72 <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>:647
     1      36   6      4,760   7      50,595  79 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:228
     2       8   1      2,040   3      52,635  82 /usr/lib/python3.9/chunk.py:51
     3       7   1      1,800   3      54,435  85 /usr/lib/python3.9/collections/__init__.py:497
     4       4   1      1,680   3      56,115  88 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:36
     5       6   1        770   1      56,885  89 <unknown>:0
     6       5   1        468   1      57,353  90 <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>:123
     7       3   0        432   1      57,785  90 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:353
     8       5   1        423   1      58,208  91 /usr/lib/python3.9/collections/__init__.py:431
     9       6   1        421   1      58,629  92 /usr/lib/python3.9/collections/__init__.py:477
<34 more rows. Type e.g. '_.more' to view.>
```

### dominated set

Another thing guppy could do is find everything a set of objects (eg. a set containing one module object) refers to, but not referred to by anything else; in other words, everything whose reference chain must go through the given set. This is through the [dominos](https://zhuyifei1999.github.io/guppy3/heapy_UniSet.html#heapykinds.IdentitySet.dominos) attribute. For example, this is everything the `wave` library have that isn't referred to by anything else:

```
>>> import wave
>>> import guppy
>>> guppy.hpy().iso(wave).dominos
Partition of a set of 601 objects. Total size = 64,664 bytes.
 Index   Count   %       Size   %   Cumulative  % Kind (class / dict of class)
     0     173  29     17,641  27      17,641  27 str
     1     173  29     13,688  21      31,329  48 tuple
     2      57   9      8,208  13      39,537  61 function
     3      52   9      7,488  12      47,025  73 types.CodeType
     4     111  18      6,631  10      53,656  83 bytes
     5       4   1      4,088   6      57,744  89 type
     6       4   1      3,288   5      61,032  94 dict of type
     7       1   0      1,192   2      62,224  96 dict of module
     8       6   1        528   1      62,752  97 property
     9       2   0        496   1      63,248  98 dict (no owner)
<10 more rows. Type e.g. '_.more' to view.>
```

However, if anything in the module is referred to by another module, then you may have to find such references to make it useful. For example, `copyreg.dispatch_table` refers to `re.Pattern`:

```
>>> import re
>>> import guppy
>>> guppy.hpy().iso(re).dominos
Partition of a set of 1 object. Total size = 88 bytes.
 Index   Count   %       Size   %   Cumulative  % Kind (class / dict of class)
     0       1 100         88 100          88 100 module
>>> import copyreg
>>> copyreg.dispatch_table
{<class 'complex'>: <function pickle_complex at 0x7ff186208d40>, <class 're.Pattern'>: <function _pickle at 0x7ff1862b7d40>}
>>> guppy.hpy().iso(re, copyreg.dispatch_table).dominos
Partition of a set of 336 objects. Total size = 48,382 bytes.
 Index   Count   %       Size   %   Cumulative  % Kind (class / dict of class)
     0      78  23     13,327  28      13,327  28 str
     1      87  26      6,808  14      20,135  42 tuple
     2      20   6      2,880   6      23,015  48 types.CodeType
     3      19   6      2,736   6      25,751  53 function
     4       6   2      2,688   6      28,439  59 dict (no owner)
     5      41  12      2,419   5      30,858  64 bytes
     6       1   0      2,288   5      33,146  69 dict of module
     7       3   1      2,224   5      35,370  73 dict of type
     8       3   1      1,864   4      37,234  77 type
     9      20   6      1,600   3      38,834  80 types.MethodDescriptorType
<19 more rows. Type e.g. '_.more' to view.>
```

Alternatively you could put everything in the library as your set:

```
>>> guppy.hpy().iso(re, re.__dict__, *re.__dict__.keys(), *re.__dict__.values()).dominos
Partition of a set of 1,621 objects. Total size = 202,064 bytes.
 Index   Count   %       Size   %   Cumulative  % Kind (class / dict of class)
     0     542  33     44,132  22      44,132  22 str
     1     422  26     38,312  19      82,444  41 tuple
     2     192  12     26,552  13     108,996  54 bytes
     3       6   0     19,904  10     128,900  64 dict of module
     4      94   6     13,656   7     142,556  71 types.CodeType
     5      84   5     12,096   6     154,652  77 function
     6       9   1      8,248   4     162,900  81 type
     7       7   0      7,512   4     170,412  84 frozenset
     8      13   1      5,752   3     176,164  87 dict (no owner)
     9       9   1      5,064   3     181,228  90 dict of type
<29 more rows. Type e.g. '_.more' to view.>
```

However, this will include every module your module refers to:

```
>>> hp.iso(re, re.__dict__, *re.__dict__.keys(), *re.__dict__.values()).dominos - hp.iso(re, copyreg.dispatch_table).dominos
Partition of a set of 1,275 objects. Total size = 153,153 bytes.
 Index   Count   %       Size   %   Cumulative  % Kind (class / dict of class)
     0     335  26     31,504  21      31,504  21 tuple
     1     454  36     30,276  20      61,780  40 str
     2     151  12     24,133  16      85,913  56 bytes
     3       5   0     17,616  12     103,529  68 dict of module
     4      74   6     10,776   7     114,305  75 types.CodeType
     5      65   5      9,360   6     123,665  81 function
     6       7   1      7,512   5     131,177  86 frozenset
     7       6   0      6,384   4     137,561  90 type
     8       7   1      3,064   2     140,625  92 dict (no owner)
     9       6   0      2,840   2     143,465  94 dict of type
<17 more rows. Type e.g. '_.more' to view.>
>>> _.byid
Set of 1,275 <mixed> objects. Total size = 153,153 bytes.
 Index      Size   %     Cumulative  %   Brief
     0     4,712   3.1       4,712   3.1 dict of module: builtins
     1     4,712   3.1       9,424   6.2 dict of module: sre_compile
     2     4,712   3.1      14,136   9.2 dict of module: sre_parse
     3     3,271   2.1      17,407  11.4 bytes: b't\x00|\x01\...x00|\x05S\x00'
     4     2,288   1.5      19,695  12.9 dict of module: _locale
     5     2,280   1.5      21,975  14.3 frozenset: 0x7ff1863cbb90
     6     2,280   1.5      24,255  15.8 frozenset: 0x7ff1863cbc80
     7     1,843   1.2      26,098  17.0 bytes: b'|\x00j\x00}...x00d\x00S\x00'
     8     1,545   1.0      27,643  18.0 bytes: b'd\x00d\x01\...x04d\x00S\x00'
     9     1,192   0.8      28,835  18.8 dict (no owner): 0x7ff18628e780*33
<1,265 more rows. Type e.g. '_.more' to view.>
```

A saner approach (still an overestimation) is to eliminate the modules from this set (because they are referred to by sys.modules):

```
>>> (hp.iso(re) | (hp.iso(re.__dict__, *re.__dict__.keys(), *re.__dict__.values()) - types.ModuleType)).dominos
Partition of a set of 424 objects. Total size = 61,004 bytes.
 Index   Count   %       Size   %   Cumulative  % Kind (class / dict of class)
     0     131  31     16,735  27      16,735  27 str
     1      96  23      7,592  12      24,327  40 tuple
     2       2   0      7,000  11      31,327  51 dict of module
     3      21   5      3,024   5      34,351  56 types.CodeType
     4       4   1      2,928   5      37,279  61 type
     5      20   5      2,880   5      40,159  66 function
     6      44  10      2,709   4      42,868  70 bytes
     7       4   1      2,600   4      45,468  75 dict of type
     8       5   1      2,440   4      47,908  79 dict (no owner)
     9      20   5      1,600   3      49,508  81 types.MethodDescriptorType
<25 more rows. Type e.g. '_.more' to view.>
>>> _ - hp.iso(re, copyreg.dispatch_table).dominos
Partition of a set of 139 objects. Total size = 19,025 bytes.
 Index   Count   %       Size   %   Cumulative  % Kind (class / dict of class)
     0       1   1      4,712  25       4,712  25 dict of module
     1      56  40      3,687  19       8,399  44 str
     2       3   2      2,224  12      10,623  56 dict of type
     3       3   2      1,864  10      12,487  66 type
     4      20  14      1,600   8      14,087  74 types.MethodDescriptorType
     5      12   9        976   5      15,063  79 tuple
     6      10   7        880   5      15,943  84 types.WrapperDescriptorType
     7       7   5        560   3      16,503  87 types.MemberDescriptorType
     8       5   4        400   2      16,903  89 types.GetSetDescriptorType
     9       3   2        360   2      17,263  91 dict of _sitebuiltins._Printer
<11 more rows. Type e.g. '_.more' to view.>
>>> _.byid
Set of 139 <mixed> objects. Total size = 19,025 bytes.
 Index      Size   %     Cumulative  %   Brief
     0     4,712  24.8       4,712  24.8 dict of module: builtins
     1     1,192   6.3       5,904  31.0 dict of type: ..Pattern
     2     1,064   5.6       6,968  36.6 type: re.error
     3       656   3.4       7,624  40.1 dict of type: ..Match
     4       410   2.2       8,034  42.2 str: 'Exception ra...e None)\n    '
     5       400   2.1       8,434  44.3 type: re.Match
     6       400   2.1       8,834  46.4 type: re.Pattern
     7       376   2.0       9,210  48.4 dict of type: ..error
     8       195   1.0       9,405  49.4 bytes: b'|\x01|\x00_...x00d\x00S\x00'
     9       160   0.8       9,565  50.3 dict of _frozen_importlib.ModuleSpec: 0x7ff1864e0490
<129 more rows. Type e.g. '_.more' to view.>
```